# Hosting public Survey123 Survey with Student trial license?

Tags: arcgis-online, license, arcgis-survey123

I am trying to create / host new surveys in Survey123 with a 1-year student license. Right now when I try to create a survey at https://survey123.arcgis.com/surveys I get the statement: "You don't have access to this feature. Required privileges: publish hosted feature layers | create new item". Similarly, if I try to link Survey123 Connect (the desktop version of Survey123) to my ArcGIS Online account, it says I do not have permission. The end goal is to create a public survey to crowd source data.

I have talked to Esri multiple times. Each time they say I should be able host public surveys but cannot help me figure it out because I have a student license.

Can this be done with this license?

Answer (score 2):

A 1-year student licence includes Survey123, so your Esri subscription isn't the problem here. The issue is that your organisation administrator hasn't given you the privileges to create and publish new content. You need to make sure that your account has been given the 'Creator' user type and 'Publisher' role. This allows you to create new content, including survey forms and feature layers. You can find out more about user types and roles in ArcGIS online here: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/roles.htm.

Answer (score -1):

An option with similar functionality https://five.epicollect.net/